# errors in csv output file; data collected from arduino

Tags: python, csv, arduino, multiprocessing

I'm creating a program needed for my master thesis. The program reads data from arduino and writes it into csv file. This is only part of the program, so I use multiprocessing module.

But the program makes a few bugs in the csv file, especially at the beginning. It should write a 3-digit number in every line. And sometimes it "eats" some digits. It looks like this:

```
308,0
,0
313,0
313,0
313,0
313,0
12,0
307,0
306,0
0,0
305,0
```

It happens randomly only in the first 100-200 lines (the whole file has several thousand lines). I don't know what causes the problem.

This is part of the program:

```
def port_reader(q, quit):
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600, timeout=0)
    while quit.empty():
        try:
            q.put(ser.readline())
        except ser.SerialTimeoutException:
            print('Data could not be read')
        time.sleep(0.04) 

def output_creator(num, q, flag, quit):
    out_path = "GSR_data/"+str(num.get())+"_GSR.csv"
    while quit.empty():
        data = q.get()
        with open(out_path, 'a') as out_file:
            try:
                out_file.write(re.sub("[^0-9]", "", data)+","+str(int(flag.value))+"\n")
            except OSError:
                print "No file"

resp_n = mp.Queue()
gsr_data = mp.Queue()
quit = mp.Queue()
flag = mp.Value('d', 0)
proc1 = mp.Process(target=port_reader, args=(gsr_data, quit))
proc2 = mp.Process(target=output_creator, args=(resp_n, gsr_data, flag, quit))
resp_n.put(resp_number)
proc1.start()
proc2.start()
```

And this is part in arduino:

```
const int analogInPin = A0;
int sensorValue = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  sensorValue = analogRead(analogInPin);
  Serial.println(sensorValue);
  delay(40);
}
```

Comment: Can you record and post the direct output of the serial of the arduino?

Comment: That Python script looks overcomplicated for what is does.

Comment: When I run only arduino, it also happens. It is probably fault of my computer, because it doesn't happen on other ones. Thanks for help, anyway. 
I know it may be overcomplicated. I am not a programmer, but I'm trying to prune it a little bit.